# Lazy Loading Angular / Ionic 3 Component AOT "is not a known element: Error"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

This is driving me crazy, hopefully someone can shed some light on the problem. I am Lazy loading my Ionic components everything works fine in development, however when I go to compile AOT throws an error.  I spent about 4 hours trying different ways to load this in I am lost, keep getting the same error.

From what I read and found in examples this should be correct. What am I missing here?

```
'tester' is not a known element: 1. If 'tester' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this 
            module. 2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. (" 
            <ion-list *ngIf="!id"> <ion-list-header> [ERROR -><tester></tester>
```

```js
//  components/tester/tester.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'tester',
  templateUrl: 'tester.html'
})
export class TesterComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello TesterComponent Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World';
  }

}
```

```js
// components/components.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TesterComponent } from './tester/tester';
import {IonicModule} from "ionic-angular";
@NgModule({
    declarations: [TesterComponent],
  imports: [IonicModule],
    exports: [TesterComponent,
    ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

```js
//  pages/faq/faq.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FaqPage } from './faq';
import {ComponentsModule} from "../../components/components.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FaqPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(FaqPage), ComponentsModule
  ],
})
export class FaqPageModule {}
```

```js
// pages/faq/faq.html
 <tester></tester>
```

EDIT

Thanks to @Joel Joseph  -  Apparently the view needs to reside in the same directory as your parent component. I had the view .html file in a shared directory hence the problem.

```
templateUrl: '../shared/view/list.html'
```

changed to

```
templateUrl: 'list.html'
```

and it compiles fine now. Will leave this up incase anyone else has this issue.

Comment: can you post the code in your main router for the root module or app.module.ts  where you have lazy loaded the feature modules

Comment: also make sure you use these syntax to [lazy load the feature  module](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)  `{path: '',  loadChildren: '../views/views.module#ViewsModule'},`

Comment: if you have used any other syntax it will end up in the error

Comment: @Joel Joseph  - Thanks man. Yup that was the issue. Apparently the view needs to reside in the same directory as your parent component.  I had the view .html file in a shared directory hence the problem.   Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Joel Joseph  -  Apparently the view needs to reside in the same directory as your parent component. I had the view .html file in a shared directory hence the problem.

```
templateUrl: '../shared/view/list.html'
```

changed to

```
templateUrl: 'list.html'
```

and it compiles fine now. Will leave this up incase anyone else has this issue.